# WordPress Permissions Roles Manager?

Tags: wordpress

I´m currently developing the Intranet for the company I am working for. The site is currently based on SharePoint, but I have to migrate it to Wordpress. And that´s my first developer experience with Wordpress, you just should know. Creating the theme, content and working with the WP Admin area works very well, but where I´m feeling defenseless is the permissions topic.

Generally, the whole page content is managed by the Marketing department. So, for me it is ok that they have access to WP Admin and I would use one of the predefined roles available.

But there will be also an area for the departments where specified users per department should be able to

- edit the pre created page content
- add subpages and edit its content (it would be nice if it can be defined which page templates can be selected by the user)
- add posts for a pre created category (that should not be changeable by the user)
- edit its profile and password

A whole access to WP Admin should be therefore prevented.

I read much information about roles, capabilities and reviewed forums and blogs presenting potential plugins. But to be honest, I´ve lost the overview and I´m totally scared about what´s the right way to do such like this the professional way.

Is there anybody who was already in such a situation or knows a good resource where to read more?

Thanks a lot.
John

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/
This is best to achieve WP user role permission.

Comment: Thank you Milap, I will give a  try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PressPermit](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/press-permit-core/) is the tool I choosed. It covers all needs described in my question.

Note: To use all features, you need to buy a support subscription currently available for $55 a year for one site.

However, a very powerful tool and in comparison to Advanced Access Manager I tried before, it really supports permissions also for multiple roles.

If you are thinking about, use the [screencasts](http://presspermit.com/tutorial/) to see if the tool cover your needs. Unfortunately, there is no trial available, but you can request an evolution wordpress installation which was setup within one day in my case. This service costs $5.